# Argument 1 passed in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have an error in my code in Laravel.

Its shows this

> Argument 1 passed to Order\Order::__construct() must be an instance of System\RewardPoint, none given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\stardibs-version2\stardibs-v2\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model.php on line 647 and defined

**order.php**

```
use BaseModel, DB; 
use Eloquent, User\User, Auth, Cart, Order\Order; 
use System\RewardPoint as RewardPoint; 

class Order extends BaseModel {

    public function __construct(RewardPoint $rewardPoint)
    {
        $this->rewardPoint = $rewardPoint;

    }
}
```

What is the solution for this?

Comment: Please, be specific about the version tag in your question.

Comment: You can [edit] your question. Its a good ideia to read the [tour] too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating the objecct of class Order you need to pass an object RewardPoint to its constructor:

```
$rewardPoint = new RewardPoint(/** whatever arguments are needed **/);
$order = new Order($rewardPoint);
```